# Issues regarding Site Catalyst DTM implementation

Tags: dynamic, tags, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have two Omniture report suite one using DTM and one using SuperTag. Both are tag management system and the purpose is to see if both can collect data at the same time to multiple report suite and the data sent to each suite are correct and not corrupted. I have a total of 5 pages all of the pages have both DTM and SuperTag embed code.

1. dtm-rpt-suite --> connected to my dev server and validated that tag fires. s_code is implemented via the DTM managed option, no s_code in my pages only DTM javascript embed. Version 1.41
2. spt-rpt-suite --> connected to my dev server and validated that tag fires. s_code is also implemented vis Supertag and not is my pages. Version H.27

All settings above are correct and I can see data in Omniture. However I see DTM capture more data then it should. It's capturing data that are being pass to SuperTag as well. I am firing DTM rules in 3 pages but

- It's also collecting data from pages where I fire rule only for superTag.
- It's also collecting data on the same page where it co-exist with superTag example if superTag was collecting 2 evar variables that are not part of DTM rule it still collects those data...

I am not sure how DTM can access other data? I am using the adobe digital pulse to validate the data collection. Is there a way to limit the data collection process? is it because the cookie set by both TMS is same? how can I explicitly add a "prefix" or "visitor namespace" in DTM? so explicitly I can confirm that the cookies set are different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Adobe Analytics code uses `s` as a namespace. So it sounds like both of your implementations are using the same *javascript* namespace, and their wires are getting crossed.

I can't speak for whether or not you can easily change the namespace within superTag, but there is a field to specify the object namespace to use, in DTM. Unfortunately, DTM does not currently allow you to both specify it, AND have DTM manage the library. So if you want to change it within DTM, you can continue to host the AA library within DTM but DTM will not automatically update the core library for you, so you will need to make sure to keep the core library code up to date.

Within DTM, navigate to the Adobe Analytics tool config.  Under **Library Management** > **Code Configuration**, select the "Custom" option.

Then in the **Code Hosted** dropdown, select "In DTM".  Open the editor box underneath it and make sure a copy of the core library is in there.

Then under that, you should see a "**Tracker Variable Name**" field. You can specify a different value to override the default `s` object here.

**Some notes about this:**

1) DTM will then reference the specified namespace in rules and other config stuff. But this will not automatically map any other existing custom code you have done within DTM.  For example, if you have a rule that manually sets `s.products` in the custom code section (DTM does not have a `s.products` field), you will need to update it to use the new namespace.

2) This is NOT the same thing as `visitorNamespace`.  `visitorNamespace` is a value you specify that becomes part of the the request domain to Adobe Analytics server.  So for example, if you have:

`s.visitorNamespace='foobar';`

You will see something along the lines of "foobar.sc.omtrdc.net" as the requested domain to Adobe.  Your actual value may be different depending on your setup but if you set `visitorNamespace` it will prefix it.

Comment: Thanks Crayon for your clarification. Very easy to follow :) I will give it a go as per your suggestion. Question once I change the Tracker Variable Name -- is it permanent for that report suite? I mean suppose my tracker variable name is "c". In future can I go back to "s" (meaning adobe hosted DTM option). Thanks

Comment: @wailer yes, you can change it whenever you want to; it's just a javascript variable name.  But in general I would recommend against using the default `s` or switching to something else short, so as to avoid namespace conflicts (like what you're facing now!)

Comment: Just confirming solution presented work for me to separate my tracking. Thank Crayon.